# Add row in a JTable with autoincrement of the last row id

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, auto-increment

My question is: how can I implement an "Add row" button which create a new row of a JTable (which gets the data from an SQLite database) with an autoincrement++ of the last row id.
The id column has the already data autoincremented, and for now I know just to create a new row with all fields blank (without an increment++ of the newest row).
Please, someone can help?

```
private void cmd_newrowActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
     ((DefaultTableModel) PrimaryTable.getModel()).addRow(new Vector());
}
```

What I want:

```
==================
id  |  data      |
==================
1   | some_data  |
2   | some_data  |
3   | some_data  |
==================


After I press addRow button:

==================
id  |  data      |
==================
1   | some_data  |
2   | some_data  |
3   | some_data  |
4   | blank      |        /// blank row data with an autoincrement of the row id
==================
```

**UPDATE:**

Ok, for now I get it how to insert a new row into database, but I don't know how to update the JXTable. So, the bellow code it works, and the new blank row it's updated after I restart the application. Someone can help me?

```
private void cmd_newrowActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    try {
        String sql = "Insert into RDSSPrimaryTable (sample_no,mineral_name,chemical_formula,main_peaks,other_peaks,reference,link,comments,spectrum) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        // no pst.setString for id - it takes automatically

        pst.setString(1, txt_sample_pt.getText());
        pst.setString(2, txt_mineral_pt.getText());
        pst.setString(3, txt_chemical_pt.getText());
        pst.setString(4, txt_main_pt.getText());
        pst.setString(5, txt_other_pt.getText());
        pst.setString(6, txt_reference_pt.getText());
        pst.setString(7, txt_link_pt.getText());
        pst.setString(8, txt_comments_pt.getText());
        pst.setBytes(9, person_image);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Inserted");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

    }

    ((DefaultTableModel) PrimaryTable.getModel()).fireTableDataChanged(); // I tried this method even if the DefaultTableModel fire table automatically.

    PrimaryTable.repaint(); //tried also repaint, revalidate - nothing happens

}
```

Comment: Why don't you let database increment your ID and then get the auto incremented ID value and dump it on JTable? So create new row first inside database with auto incremented ids and then read it back to show it inside JTable

Comment: With an insert statement and (?) value?

Comment: so what is the difficult part? just insert row without value and read the last row's ID

Comment: after I read the number of all rows? the next step?

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them - **now**

Answer (score 0):

create a sequence in your database using following code

```
CREATE SEQUENCE sample_number
  START WITH     1
  INCREMENT BY   1;
```

After that in your code make following changes:

```
String sql = "Insert into RDSSPrimaryTable (sample_no,mineral_name,chemical_formula,main_peaks,other_peaks,reference,link,comments,spectrum) values (sample_number.nextval(),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

pst.setString(1, txt_mineral_pt.getText());
pst.setString(2, txt_chemical_pt.getText());
pst.setString(3, txt_main_pt.getText());
pst.setString(4, txt_other_pt.getText());
pst.setString(5, txt_reference_pt.getText());
pst.setString(6, txt_link_pt.getText());
pst.setString(7, txt_comments_pt.getText());
pst.setBytes(8, person_image);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. The increment row it's solved by the database itself, which have the first column ID's with AUTO INCREMENT option. The problem now is that the newly created row does not appear in JXTable. Appear just after I restart my application. Any suggestion?